# Wordpress Upload : File size must be at least 512 KB?

Tags: wordpress, upload

I try to import a PDF file on my wordpress uploader. And, Wordpress tell me that : 
"File size must be at least 512 KB."

My pdf is too small ! I know how to increase the upload limit size on Wordpress, but not how to decrease the upload file limit.

I found nothing on google or here. Is someone have already had this issue ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The limitation of the pdf size file was set on 512kb for the Contact 7 Form I've made. :)